# Как компонент Unity Toggle(переключатель с галочкой) меняет bool свойство у другого объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как компонент Unity Toggle(переключатель с галочкой) меняет bool свойство у другого объекта?

Я пытаюсь сделать скрипт который бы принимал bool свойство другого(заданного в редакторе) скрипта и менял его при необходимости.
Но bool не ссылочный тип, перетащить его и как то выбрать не получается.

А компонент Toggle может принимать ссылку на bool свойство, и изменять его.
Вроде он делает это с помощью UnityEvent. Но я не могу понять как. Я не могу посмотреть код unity чтобы понять как он это делает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался использовать поле UnityEvent<bool>, появляется такое же окошко, но как из unityEvent достать ссылку на bool значение не понимаю.

---

### Кое что понял через некоторое время:

В unityEvent хранится название нужного свойства "set_EnableMouse".
И есть ссылка на экземпляр.
Теперь я могу обращаться к нему по имени и менять его значение.
Но получить значение не получается.

```
public UnityEvent<bool> unityEvent;

void Start()
{
    var obj = unityEvent.GetPersistentTarget(0);
    string propertyName = unityEvent.GetPersistentMethodName(0);

    Type t = obj.GetType();

    // ---Это работает---
    // Задаю значение
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(propertyName);
    method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { false });

    // ---Это не работает---
    // Получаю значение
    PropertyInfo property = t.GetProperty(propertyName);
    Debug.Log($"значение = {property.GetValue(obj)}");
    // выдаёт null - скорее всего из за того что свойство называется set_EnableMouse а не EnableMouse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш toggle (или слайдер, или другой UI элемент, у которого ивент с аргументом), использовал аргумент, то в эдиторе, при выборе нужного метода из скрипта, нужно выбирать метод из верхнего списка `dynamic`
[image: Пример]

Класс Test:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool myBool;

    public void ChangeBool(bool b)
    {
        myBool = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но проблема не в этом. Я пытаюсь сделать скрипт в который можно перетащить ссылку на любое поле.
UnityEvent может записать значение, но прочитать значение не может. Или это я не могу.